# How much faster is dreamweaver?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

Hey everyone I just bought the master cs5 suite mostly for design purposes, and now I have a lot of peoPle telling me I should start using DW instead of hand coding my HTML/CSS because it will speed up my production and it's what all design shops use and is an industry standard . I was curious if this is accurate and how much would it really speed things up?

Comment: I use Notepad++ for coding and I found this question interesting.. I mean i want to see some answers. Personally i dont believe that it has many advantages really.. Though for productivity increase you might want to check out ZenCoding: http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/ Ive been in DW courses and in one i learned one thing that seemed very useful as far as very basic html websites go, it allowed you to basically store code into some library and call that piece of code into the document so that you dont have to change same thing in multiple html documents.. but... idk.. something like that.

Answer (score 3):

I (personally) disagree. I use DW in CS5 for code editing view only (it has the best markup/code highlighting I've found); the generated markup is not great, so I don't use it, nor am I highly trained in the workflow it entails. A lot of designers will not understand hand coding markup, but that's usually because they don't understand how to or don't care to do so because it's not what they get paid to do.

However, if you're working on (a) lower level, you have a better understanding of your markup/styles/code. It may take slightly/significantly more effort (depending on your abilities hand coding), but I personally think it's worth the effort in many cases. However, I am not a piece worker nor am I paid on deadlines.

There are other reasons I use DW (WebDAV support, searching capabilities), but I will likely never use it to author my markup. Also note I don't pay for it.

Comment: WebDAV was great to have at one place I worked. And, you're right about the highlighting. DW has gotten better over the years especially with highlighting code errors.

Comment: I work at a university where to publish to my department's site, I have to use WebDAV. I have yet to find anything comparable in that area. :S

Comment: Ha...I was working at a university when I used it last :)

Comment: That's pretty funny. I actually do like DW a lot, but I would struggle to pay for it without learning a lot more about how it's intended to work.

Answer (score 1):

Dreamweaver CS5.5 made a lot of improvements over previous versions. As a designer you may appreciate Live Preview and the design integration's. As a coding IDE, it's still considered sub-standard and many developers choose to go another route. I use PHPdesinger 7 for ~$70, its got in-line xdebug integration and pretty good intellisense for PHP, CI, and jQuery. I use DW5.5 and PHPdesigner and I find it's far less bloated then Dreamweaver for what I use it for, coding with PHP/Jquery and web API's. I also feel that it's closer to how I worked before using advanced IDE's like this, coding on my Macbook with Coda. But if your designing web pages you may like Dreamweaver better.

Comment: also, I'm yet to find good bundle integration with Dreamweaver. If your big on using frameworks and libraries, you may find something simple with built in bundle editors like N++ far better.

Answer (score 1):

Used unwisely it won't speed it up at all. You'll spend more time pulling out DW's extraneous code. Use parts of DW that will make you faster like snippets (for storing snippets of code you use frequently) and find and replace (using f&r with regex is a very useful skill). I use it to cram in table markup quickly (for data tables). Dragging files over for internal links is quite nice and the keyboard shortcuts help (you can create custom ones).

That said, I like the product at work. Check in and check out has been very helpful there with multiple coders/designers.

So, there are plenty of parts in DW that will speed up your hand coding. Root them out.

Comment: The search functionality is pretty good. One of my favorites.